# What is special about pierogi dough?

Tags: dough, dumplings

I wanted to make home-made pierogis. Is there a special dough that needs to be used?  I wanted the pierogis to be fairly thick - what type of dough would work best?

Answer (score 8):

Some pierogi recipes include sour cream in the dough; they also often have more egg than a typical basic pasta dough.

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine using a regular homemade pasta dough.

I learned to make perogis with a standard egg dough - egg, flour, water, and oil.  The filling is dry curd cottage cheese, salt, and eggs.  To shape them we use a nifty hand tart cutter that I can't find online anywhere.  Then we boil them in water for about 10 minutes to cook.  Serve with melted butter.

Answer (score 2):

Like @justkt said you should be fine using regular homemade pasta dough. If you want something more specific though I used [this recipe](http://www.food.com/recipe/homemade-cottage-cheese-pierogies-perogies-the-old-fashioned-66654) from Food.com. Its super good. Especially since I also made the cottage cheese myself as well.

Comment: wait, wait, you made dry curd cottage cheese yourself?  I can't find it anywhere where I live and you have no idea how happy it would make my spouse if I were able to make it.  Pointers?

Comment: @justkt I am unsure if this is dry curd but I found the cottage cheese recipe here http://www.food.com/recipe/cottage-cheese-382707. In your opinion is this dry curd?

Comment: looks like it may well be, as long as you didn't add extra dairy to it.  See here: http://www.news-leader.com/article/20070228/COLUMNISTS19/702280317/Dry-cottage-cheese-can-be-found-or-made-at-home

Comment: @justkt - I didn't add anything to the cottage cheese so it must be. Thanks for clearing dry curd cottage cheese up. :) Hope the recipe helps. :D

Answer (score 2):

Quite often pierogi doughs are vegan, especially if you are making the peirogies for X-mas eve (where in many sects, you don't eat meat the on X-mas eave, and fish is not considered a meat).

> 2 cups flour
>   ~1/2 cup warm water
>   1/4 cup vegetable oil
>   1 teaspoon salt
>
> Mix all together, and give it a little knead to make it consistent, but no 
>   more - otherwise you'll make the dough tough

Then you roll out the dough, cut circles with a large mouth jar or a glass, stuff and pinch closed. Boil till dough is cooked or par-boil and then fry in a pan. Add onions, butter and bacon to taste.

Typical fillings include mashed potatoes (sometimes with cheese), cottage cheese (dry), sour kraut, fruit (desert), rarely cooked meat - anything you can stuff in it.

(yah I know, I mentioned vegan earlier, but vegan tastes a lot better when you add butter and bacon *rim-shot*)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you make'm.

5 cups of flour
5 eggs
8 oz's of sour cream
1/4 cup of water....

That makes the dough, cover it with a towel for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generation recipe for a light pierogy dough;

4 cups flour
2 eggs
5 TBSP sour cream
3 TBSP oil
3/4 cup water

as noted above, add you filling and toss in boiling water. When they float their done.

I use a Chinese basket brush to retrieve from the water and toss in fried onions and butter to prevent sticking.